# Android Room SQL Query for number of occurrences between two dates

Tags: android, mysql, android-room

I'm Currently working on an a financial app which has the same kind of custom repeating possibilities as Google Calendar, to allow for abnormal payment patterns (thinking of daily pay each week etc) but I've run into a bit of an issue when selecting the data from the database where a 'transaction' has not yet completed its repeat.

Here is the database structure I am using for the transactions table;

```
id - String
cost - long
start_date - long
type - int
title - String
category_id - String
repeat_end_date - long
repeat_end_occurrence - int
repeat_frequency - int
repeat_frequency_units - int
repeat_weekly_days - int
repeat_monthly_day - int
```

From this I want to select all transactions between two dates, but the occurrences part has me stumped. For example, I have a transaction that repeats weekly on a monday and tuesday for 7 occurrences. How would I do this in the above?

the repeat_weekly_days is what I would need to use here, as the repeat_weekly_days is a bitmask in the following format;

```
(Unused) | Sunday | Saturday | Friday | Thursday | Wednesday | Tuesday | Monday
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: The above is not a transaction, but a pattern (series vs occurance in calendar terms). I would store the transactions in a separate table where you link the transaction to the pattern with a foreign key.

Comment: Yes the above is basically the series and I have a separate adjustments table which stores which fields are changed for a specific date. What Im thinking is that I need to return the 'series' data in this case called 'transactions' where the series would have a transaction in that range. Thanks for the above link, I will have a look